# How to remove NTFS partition in Ubuntu Launcher?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu, and just installed Ubuntu12.04 along with a dual boot for Windows 7.

And I was following some tutorial on booting up Ubuntu with the NTFS partition of Windows 7 mounted, I did that because I need some files from that partition although I can access it on Nautilus after mounting it.

The problem is after following some tutorial, I want it to behave like before, so I tried messing with /etc/fstab file.

My problem now is I can't remove the partition icons on the launchpad

Screenshot [image: link [here][1]]

And when I go to Nautilus I can't unmount them, because it says

> Unabe to unmount [parition name]
>
> Error unmounting: umount exited with
> exit code 1: helper failed with: umount: only root can unmount
> /dev/sda1 from /media/sda1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this commad on terminal,

```
gksu nautilus
```

Then unmount the `/dev/sda1` ntfs drive which was appeared on the devices list.

OR

Try this command on terminal

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to unmount it from **Disks** or by removing the NTFS partition entry from **fstab**.